# javascript value for CheckboxFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

checkboxFor renders the following for a checkbox:

```
<input id="IsCredit" name="IsCredit" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="IsCredit" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

In javascript,

```
$('#IsCredit').val();
```

is ALWAYS true. Whether ticked or unticked

How can I determine if the checkbox has been ticked in Javascript?

Comment: if(document.getElementById("#IsCredit").checked){}else{}

Comment: straight HTML5 check : IsCredit.checked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check it's `checked` property. With jQuery:

```
var isChecked = $('#IsCredit').prop("checked");
```

Or with native DOM methods:

```
var isChecked = document.getElementById("IsCredit").checked;
```

Answer (score 2):

`val` returns a value of a form element, as your element has a `true` value, `val()` returns `true` not it's checked property value,  you can use `prop` method for reading `checked` property of a checkbox, or `is` method.

```
if ( $('#IsCredit').is(':checked') {
    // ...
}
```

or:

```
var checked = $('#IsCredit').prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#IsCredit").attr('checked')` will tell you if it's checked. You can also use a second parameter true/false to check/uncheck the checkbox.

Per comment, use `prop` instead of `attr` when available. E.g:

```
$("#IsCredit").prop('checked')
```